# Sorting Map values in descending order with Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy, dictionary

I have a `Map<String,Integer>` whose entries (keys) need to be sorted in order of **descending value**. For instance, if the map looks like:

```
"a" => 5
"b" => 3
"c" => 12
"d" => 9
```

The after sorting it needs to look like:

```
"c" => 12
"d" => 9
"a" => 5
"b" => 3
```

My best attempt thus far:

```
def test() {
    Map<String,Integer> toSort = new HashMap<String,Integer>()
    toSort.put("a", 5)
    toSort.put("b", 3)
    toSort.put("c", 12)
    toSort.put("d", 9)

    Map<String,Integer> sorted = sortMapDesc(toSort)
    sorted.each {
        println "${it.key} has a value of ${it.value}."
    }
}

def sortMapDesc(Map<String,Integer> toSort) {
    println "Sorting..."
    println toSort

    // The map of properly sorted entries.
    Map<String,Integer> sorted = new HashMap<String,Integer>()

    // Keep scanning the map for the key with the highest value. When we find
    // it, add it as the next entry to the 'sorted' map, and then zero it out
    // so it won't show up as the highest on subsequent scans/passes. Stop scanning
    // when the entire 'toSort' map contains keys with zeros.
    while(!mapIsAllZeros(toSort)) {
        int highest = -1
        String highestKey = ""
        toSort.each {
            if(it.value > highest) {
                highest = it.value
                highestKey = it.key
            }
        }

        toSort.put(highestKey, 0)
        sorted.put(highestKey, highest)
    }

    sorted
}

def mapIsAllZeros(Map<String,Integer> toCheck) {
    toCheck.values().every{!it}
}
```

When I run `test()` I get the following output:

```
Sorting...
[d:9, b:3, c:12, a:5]
d has a value of 9.
b has a value of 3.
c has a value of 12.
a has a value of 5.
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You mean sort the values? Not the keys as in the question?

Answer (score 16):

Just do:

```
​def m = [a:​5, b:12, c:3, d:9]
def sorted = m.sort { a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
```

Comment: Another option is just: `m.sort { -it.value }`

Comment: @tim_yates hi, could you explain what this closure means  a, b -> b.value <=> a.value   .. thanks :)

Comment: @user3714598, `<=>` is the "spaceship operator". It delegates to the `compareTo` method. See [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spaceship_operator) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To do the sorting, Tim's implementation is the way to go.  But if you're just wondering why your example code doesn't work as you expect, the answer is that the variable 'sorted' needs to be of type LinkedHashMap, rather than just HashMap.  You can set it explicitly:

```
Map<String,Integer> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>()
```

Or, just do this:

```
Map<String,Integer> sorted = [:]
```